# Alamofire 5 type 'Request' has no member 'authorizationHeader'

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

After updating to Alamofire 5 "Request.authorizationHeader(user: String, password: String)" method show error.

```
Error:- Type 'Request' has no member 'authorizationHeader'
```

Code:

```
    // Safely unwrap token
    guard let safeHeader = Request.authorizationHeader(user: consumerKey!, password: consumerSecret!) else {
        return nil
    }
```

Comment: Which version of Alamofire are you using?

Comment: Bundle version string (short)  5.0.5

Comment: What do you mean by "not working", do you have any error or you expect something that is not showing up? If any of these, can you post the error or what you expect?

Comment: update question please check @denis_lor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What used to be under `Request.authorizationHeader(..)` is now under `HTTPHeaders.authorization(..)`, to better explain it I'll put here the code how it has changed:

Before [this commit](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/commit/3e488dcd5caf8d76f3da79c7b6d7f4d784ca3296#diff-c30cd913449e44231db15ad8bc26c037L187) we had in Request.swift:

```
/// Returns a base64 encoded basic authentication credential as an authorization header tuple.
///
/// - parameter user:     The user.
/// - parameter password: The password.
///
/// - returns: A tuple with Authorization header and credential value if encoding succeeds, `nil` otherwise.
open class func authorizationHeader(user: String, password: String) -> (key: String, value: String)? {
    guard let data = "\(user):\(password)".data(using: .utf8) else { return nil }
    let credential = data.base64EncodedString(options: [])
    return (key: "Authorization", value: "Basic \(credential)")
}
```

Since [this commit](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/commit/3e488dcd5caf8d76f3da79c7b6d7f4d784ca3296#diff-c30cd913449e44231db15ad8bc26c037L187) in **Alamofire 5** we can find it within `HTTPHeaders.swift`:

```
/// Returns a `Basic` `Authorization` header using the `username` and `password` provided.
///
/// - Parameters:
///   - username: The username of the header.
///   - password: The password of the header.
///
/// - Returns:    The header.
public static func authorization(username: String, password: String) -> HTTPHeader {
    let credential = Data("\(username):\(password)".utf8).base64EncodedString()

    return authorization("Basic \(credential)")
}
```

That means now you should be able to do the same by doing:

```
let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
        .authorization(username: consumerKey!, password: consumerSecret!),
        .accept("application/json")
    ]
```